# Getting an error 'argument of AND must be type Boolean, not type integer' when I try to get two columns from a table(table from subquery) using `and`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a query to get the `first_name` and `last_name` of  employees who those have the highest salary in each `department` from the following table
[image]

and I have tried a query like the following

```
 select "FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME" 
 from "Worker" 
 where "SALARY" 
   and "DEPARTMENT"  IN (select "DEPATMENT", max("SALARY") 
                         from "Worker"  
                         group by "DEPARTMENT" );
```

but getting an error

```
ERROR:  argument of AND must be type Boolean, not type integer
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to `where "SALARY"` which is not valid boolean expression.

If that error wasn't reported, you would hit the "next" error with the expression `"DEPARTMENT"  IN (select "DEPATMENT", max("SALARY") ...)`.

If the sub-query returns two columns, you can't compare it with just one column on the left side.

You probably meant to write:

```
select "FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME" 
from "Worker" 
where ("DEPARTMENT", "SALARY")  IN (select "DEPARTMENT", max("SALARY") 
                                    from "Worker"  
                                    group by "DEPARTMENT");
```

Comment: Typeo Should be: where ("DEPARTMENT", "SALARY")  IN (select "DEPARTMENT", max("SALARY").